# Make pivot with duplicates that are equal

Tags: pandas, pivot

I want to make a pivot from a dataframe with multiple duplicates in 'index' and 'column', where the values I want are always equal when 'index' and 'column' are duplicates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"foo": ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two'],
...                    "bar": ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
...                    "baz": [1, 1, 3, 4]})
```

But I get:
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

when I try

```
df.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicaites().pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')`

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz', agg_func='first')`

Comment: This is great!  I had extra columns that made the overall row not a duplicate, but was able to specify only the desired rows!  Thanks Yoben!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1 = df[~df.duplicated()].pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='baz')
print(df1)

bar    A    B    C
foo
one  1.0  NaN  NaN
two  NaN  3.0  4.0
```